# How to implement Theil–Sen estimator in R?

Tags: r

I would like to use Theil–Sen estimator in R, I found the package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zyp/zyp.pdf but i get an error installing it using:

```
install.packages(zyp)


> install.packages(zyp)
Errore in install.packages(zyp) : oggetto "zyp" non trovato
```

It just telling me that there is no zyp package, I can't install it.

Do you know other libraries with this method?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty trivial, but you just need quotation marks around `"zyp"`:

```
install.packages("zyp")
```

In your defense, R is not always consistent about whether quotation marks are required: for example `library()` can take *either* quoted or un-quoted input; `save()` requires the name of the object to save; `object.size()` requires the object itself ...

To help you with future interpretation of error messages:

```
oggetto "zyp" non trovato
```

(or 'object "zyp" not found') means R couldn't find an R object in the workspace called `zyp`.  The error message you would have gotten if you had tried to install a non-existent package would be (a suitable translation of):

```
> install.packages("junk")
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘junk’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0 alpha)
```

PS you might want to consider rephrasing/retitling your question, as it really has nothing to do with the Theil-Sen estimator ... just with installing packages in R

Answer (score 0):

I suspect most fully stocked repositories have it. I just check the CMU repo at: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN and version 0.9-1 is there. There are often hours on Sundays when maintenance is being done and generally just switching to another repository will solve the problem.